# Foundation compiling sass using PyCharm

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I am experimenting with Foundation sites, compiling the sass using PyCharm.

Having created a folder called foundation, I've installed the files as per the site instructions

```
cd foundation
npm install foundation-sites --save
```

I have created a folder at the root of my project (the same level as the foundation folder) called sass-test, and in this I have a file called custom.scss and at the top I have:

```
@import "../foundation/node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/settings";
@import "../foundation/node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation";
```

The paths are correct.

Below that I have just entered something simple to test the compilation eg

```
body {
  background:red;
}
```

Having set up my file watcher in PyCharm, the code does compile to the sass-test folder, but the compiled css only includes the body rule. None of css has been compiled from settings.scss or foundation.scss

Not having used sass much at all, can someone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the util directory.
E.G

```
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/util';     
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss';  

// Settings  
@include foundation-global-styles;  
@include foundation-grid;  
@include foundation-typography;  
@include foundation-forms;  `
```

etc etc..

I loaded all the settings this way as I didn't need to use everything that came down, but if you want the whole lot you can presumably just include the settings partial the same way. I think primarily for me the issue was not loading the utils.

That's how I got my framework partial to compile from node_modules, no experience with Pycharm though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I find the docs for Foundation if you don't want to use gulp or bower to be a bit of a pain - spent ages figuring out what I'd done wrong, glad to be able to pass it along!

Comment: You're right - they are not good - your help has saved a lot of time! When you use the foundation-cli you get the settings as you've described here (I've used it before) but do you know where the equivalent is when you use npm as I've shown above? Also, can't find the motion ui?

Comment: @Newfoundland I can't answer about motion-ui -  I was under the impression that it was a standalone library, it does say in the [foundation docs](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/motion-ui.html) that it comes packaged in the starter projects though, not much good for me as I only really want the framework. As for the settings I copied all the import statements into my own framework partial and just remove anything I know I won't use. I removed the if statement regarding which grid to use though (`@mixin foundation-everything`).